# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_24 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (16, 10, 1)

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm trying to make a toy neural network that simply learns how to sort an array, it's just an experiment, but still I can't seem to make it function when using LSTMs, I'm probably missing something about the input/output shape requirements.

Here's the code, I'm writing everything from the data creation, you can skip it and go directly to the fit error at the end:

Data Creation:

```
n=20
m=10
test_r=0.1
val_r=0.1

int(n*(val_r+test_r))
X=np.random.rand(n,m)
Y=np.sort(X, axis=1)

val_n=int(n*(val_r))
test_n=int(n*(test_r))

X_train=X[:n-val_n-test_n]
X_val=X[n-val_n-test_n:n- test_n]
X_test=X[n-test_n:]
y_train=Y[:n-val_n-test_n]
y_val=Y[n-val_n-test_n:n- test_n]
y_test=Y[n-test_n:]
```

Here I build the model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential,Model
from keras.layers import Dense,Input,LSTM, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

def model_build():
  in_x = Input(shape=(m,1))
  x = LSTM(128,activation='relu')(in_x)
  x=Dense(m)(x)
  model = Model(inputs=in_x, output=x)
  return model
```

The model builds just fine:

```
model = model_build()
model.summary()


Model: "model_23"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_28 (InputLayer)        (None, 10, 1)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_28 (LSTM)               (None, 128)               66560     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 67,850
Trainable params: 67,850
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: UserWarning: Update your `Model` call to the Keras 2 API: `Model(inputs=Tensor("in..., outputs=Tensor("de...)`
```

It also compiles without problems:

```
model= model_build()
opt = Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-5)
chkpt = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/content/drive/My Drive/CoLab/h5py/best_forecast2mse.h5',monitor='mean_squared_error', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)
chkpt2 = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='/content/drive/My Drive/CoLab/h5py/best_forecast2mae.h5',monitor='mean_absolute_error', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)
callbacks_list=[chkpt,chkpt2]
model.compile(loss='mse', metrics=['mse','mae'],optimizer=opt)
```

I reshape the data in the format suitable for LSTMs:

```
y_train=np.reshape(y_train,np.shape(y_train)+(1,) )
X_train=np.reshape(X_train,np.shape(X_train)+(1,) )
```

It's in the shape of (n_samples,n_steps,n_variables) so it should work:

```
np.shape(X_train), np.shape(y_train)

((16, 10, 1), (16, 10, 1))
```

I try to fit:

```
    H=model.fit(X_train,y_train, validation_data=(X_val,y_val), callbacks=callbacks_list, epochs=100)
```

It gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-f68ddc068cd4> in <module>()
----> 1 H=model.fit(X_train,y_train, validation_data=(X_val,y_val), callbacks=callbacks_list, epochs=100)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1152             sample_weight=sample_weight,
   1153             class_weight=class_weight,
-> 1154             batch_size=batch_size)
   1155 
   1156         # Prepare validation data.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    619                 feed_output_shapes,
    620                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 621                 exception_prefix='target')
    622 
    623             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    133                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    134                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 135                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    136                 if not check_batch_axis:
    137                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_24 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (16, 10, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your model produces an output that has a shape of `(batch_size, 10)`. You can tell this from the last line of `model.summary()`. This output needs to have the **same shape** with the target output so that it can be compared in the loss function. Instead you pass it a target that has a shape of `(16, 10, 1)`.

In order for this to work you need your target output to have a shape of `(16, 10)`. The shape that you try to make (i.e. `(n_samples, n_steps, n_variables)`) is only applicable for the input, **not the output**.

To make this work just remove this line from your code:

```py
y_train = np.reshape(y_train, np.shape(y_train) + (1,))
```

Comment: Do I have to reshape only the input and leave the y_train as (n,m)? I tried to do that it gives me another error, I think this problem has timestep=1 so maybe lstm is not suitable. (it was just an experiment anyway) Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If I reshape only the X, it gives me this error: "Error when checking input: expected input_10 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 10)"

Comment: You reshape only `y` not `x`. I edited my answer to be more clear.